# How to include remote maven dependencies in an Android library

Tags: android, maven, jar, gradle, aar

I have a very complex problem. My company developed an SDK, and the result is an AAR file that has been published on a remote Maven repository (which can be accessed anonymously). However, this AAR has several dependencies, for example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/BluetoothLeLibrary-0.0.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

    compile 'com.company.sdk.client:sdk-client-lib:1.2.1.1@jar'
    compile 'com.company.internal.commons:enums:1.0@jar'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
}
```

The ones that start with com.company are private libraries that our company uses. They are located on another Maven repo, that is only accessible to employees and collaborators using a username and password.

Now, this AAR file can be used by any developer in order to access its features. However, if the dependency is added like shown on Code Sample A, the build process breaks, since it requires access to Google Play Services variable @integer/google_play_services_version used in the Android Manifest. I found two workarounds for this, shown on Code Sample B and C. However, by using Code Sample B, the app that uses the SDK tries to download and access the company's private libraries; but since they are only accessible through a user and password, they are simply not found by gradle. On the other hand, Code Sample C leaves the app unable to find classes and methods on those libraries; weirdly enough, the code compiles and runs, but the app crashes with a java.lang.VerifyError and rejecting the SDK's classes.

How can I add these private libraries to the AAR, in order to avoid the app to try to download them? Or how could I solve this issue?

Code Sample A:

```
compile 'com.company.sdk:library:1.3.0.0@aar'
```

Code Sample B:

```
compile ('com.company.sdk:library:1.3.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

Code Sample C:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
compile ('com.company.cc.sdk:library:1.3.0.2@aar'){
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module:'play-services-location')
}
```